# Multiple Entries in VBA for Cell COmparison

Tags: vba

[image]

I don't really understand VBA but I would like to use VBA for Message Pop Up. Come up with a simple VBA and struck on how to continue.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Range("D10").Value > Range("D11") Then
    MsgBox "Allowable Quota for Office, Exceeded! Please kindly Work From Home"
End If
End Sub
```

I have multiple cells to compare such as F10 & F11, H10 & H11, L10 & L11. How do i insert multiple entries into VBA? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things to think about here.
You could just make more `if`s, or use `or` to check multiple conditions:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Range("D10").Value > Range("D11") Or _
    Range("F10").Value > Range("F11") Or _
    Range("H10").Value > Range("H11") Or _
    Range("L10").Value > Range("L11") Then
    MsgBox "Allowable Quota for Office, Exceeded! Please kindly Work From Home"
End If

End Sub
```

An alternative to this would be looping through all the cases, like so:

```
Dim test_range As Range, cell As Variant
Set test_range = Range("D10, F10, H10, L10")
For Each cell In test_range
    If cell.Value > cell.Offset(1).Value Then
        MsgBox "Allowable Quota for Office, Exceeded! Please kindly Work From Home"
    End If
Next cell
```

Sure, this works, but has a couple of problems;

1. All the checks run every time something is changed. While it's not a huge problem right now, the document could get slow if more things are checked.
2. It will display the message every time anything is changed, until the numbers causing the message is changed.
3. It doesn't say what cell is causing the pop-up.

One way, to only run the code when the relevant cells are changed, is with the `intersect` function. Like this:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D10, F10, H10, L10")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target > Target.Offset(1) Then
        MsgBox "Allowable Quota for Office, Exceeded! Please kindly Work From Home"
    End If
End If
```

In this specific case, we will however only get the error when changing in `10`, not `11`, which you could alleviate by doing the check in reverse for those.
Another problem with this method is that it might not trigger if these cells are change with a function, rather than a direct change of the cell value.

Hope that these examples help a little with ideas.

Comment: A very comprehensive answer.

Comment: Thanks Christofer for your kind explanation. I will adpot your first solution. I am totally nerd with VBA but your first solution is much simpler for me to grasp with. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Weber, if i need to set another set of message for another table, how can i continue from the first solution?

Comment: If you want to keep it within the same piece of code, you could use `elseif` before `End if`  and add new conditions and actions. If that is what you need.

Comment: Thanks I will try it out. Greatly appreciate your kind help